# Database Design - One table or multiple tables/joins

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have an existing database that is structured as follows:

```
user
user_profile
user_permissions
user_statistics
```

Each table has a unique column which is used to join each table together, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_profile ON user.user_id = user_profile.user_profile_id
INNER JOIN user_permissions ON user.user_id = user_permissions.user_permissions_id
INNER JOIN user_statistics ON user.user_id = user_statistics.user_statistics_id
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Is there anything wrong with doing things this way or is it better practice to create one table with lots of columns, so that no joins are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic database design; it's called "[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)", and is generally considered best practice.

There are reasons to de-normalize a database - performance is the classic. However, that typically comes at the expense of maintainability and consistency. It usually only makes sense at the very extremes of data size - the schema you describe should scale to huge numbers of records without the joins becoming a problem.

I'm also guessing that several of the tables linked to "user" have more than one record for a given user - "statistics" typically has lots of rows for a given user; permissions may also have one row for each user's permission. Modelling that in a single big table would be horrible.

Some designers like to create separate tables for data that is logically separate. So, your design may include a "user_profile" table with a single row per user because the designer felt that this is logically separate data from "user" - it changes under different business circumstances, for instance. This is mostly a matter of style, in my view.

Joins do not make your database slower in this case - the whole point of a relational database is to be very efficient at managing this kind of scenario ("relational" refers to the fact that data can be related).

Comment: OK, so in terms of best practice, the only time I should need to split my data is when I have a single user record in "user" and multiple records that relate to the user record in the other tables like statistics and permissions? Does using joins slow down the database query?

Comment: It *can* speed it up; it depends on the nature of the data you are storing.

Comment: Joins will slow you down if you do not index correctly. The FK should have an index and not all databases will give it one automatically as part of creating the FK. You may need one-to-one relationships if you have fields that will rarely be filled out (or queries) or very wide tables. very wide tables can cause slow performance or worse inability to add a the information you need due to record size constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make the database relational, as it is. This structure will eliminate risk of data anomalies and is ready for changes in scale and domain specifics (i.e. what happens when you add a new kind of permission?)

JOINs are a natural part of what databases do, and they are very efficient.

The specifics of why this is good practice are gathered together into what we call [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)